# Is there a way to assert the direction of a page in Testcafe? (e.g. assert RTL is true)

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, testcafe

I am about to write an integration test for a webapp with functionality to flip between RTL and LTR via <dir="auto">. In testcafe, is there a way to dictate or assert that the direction is RTL or would I have to output something in the page source to assert on?

Any help on this would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to assert it is to use `eval` or `ClientFunction`. For example:

```js
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const getDocumentDirection = ClientFunction(() => {
  return getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).direction;
})

fixture('Getting Started')
  .page('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example');

test('My first test', async t => {

  await t
    .expect(getDocumentDirection()).eql('ltr');
});
```

Comment: That works exactly as I needed! Thanks a million!